# How to remove the duplicate record while uploading the excel in c# using bulk upload

Tags: c#

Here is my query I want to add extra option to remove the duplicate file while upload.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rollno;
    String sname;
    String fname;
    String mname;

    string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    path = path.Replace("1", "4");
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/") + path);
    String ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/") + path;
    OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + ExcelPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; Persist Security Info = False");
    mycon.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", mycon);
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // Response.Write("<br/>"+dr[0].ToString());
        rollno = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
        sname = dr[1].ToString();
        fname = dr[2].ToString();
        mname = dr[3].ToString();

        SqlConnection n = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bu1-d22x7n62\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dummy;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd");
        n.Open();
        savedata(rollno, sname, fname, mname);
    }
    Label3.Text = "Data Has Been Saved Successfully";
}

private void savedata(int rollno1, String sname1, String fname1, String mname1)
{
    String query = "insert into studentdetail(rollno,name,fathername,mothername) values(" + rollno1 + ",'" + sname1 + "','" + fname1 + "','" + mname1 + "')";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bu1-d22x7n62\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dummy;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In this I have add bulk upload option by clicking on the button and I want to alter in this query for removing duplicate record

Comment: U can use distinct or groupby or where condition in your query

Comment: you should read up on the following `sql injection, how to construct parameterized querys` also you could use `WHERE ID NOT IN` for example.. personally I would read up about how to create and use stored procedures when you get some spare time too

Comment: @newbie. Yes but i dont know how to add the distinct query in this . Can u give some ideas

Comment: @AravindhanR are you a `Newbie to GOOGLE SEARCHES?` start with a simple google search and search for how to construct a Select Distinct query

Comment: @Methodman. Thanku

Comment: I recomend you look into `Table Valued Parameters` and `MERGE statements`

Comment: I assumed that you copy the code blindly. If simple sql query you don’t even bother to google . You can forget about becoming a developer

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("path to file name"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("path to file name");
        }
        else
        {
            //do you other stuff here
        }
```

Comment: Your post [went into the Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17930882) because somebody flagged it as either "Not An Answer" or "Very Low Quality". This is (in my opinion) an incorrect flag - see [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/284827), which says: "**When should I not use this flag?**: The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it". Your post should have been downvoted, not flagged.

Comment: While I think you answer has been incorrectly flagged, you should really expand it to explain *why* it answers the question - why does deleting the file help, etc., etc.

Comment: The OP posted a ?: "Here is my query I want to add extra option to remove the duplicate file while upload." which says he wants to remove the duplicate file during upload.  The only answers that I see posted are for inserting the results into the database.  I tried to answer the original post. My interpretation of this question is that the OP has a directory with files, and during upload grabs a duplicate file.  This snippet will remove the duplicate.